# How can my developer on Linux checkin code to my Visual Studio Team System project?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, tfs

I have a developer working in Linux. He is developing html5 stuff that needs to be checked in to my project instance in Visual Studio Team System.

What kind of tools should he use to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git for source control?

Comment: I guess TFVC is for Visual Studio Online?

Comment: TFVC is one of the two options for source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Team Explorer Everywhere](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413285(v=vs.120).aspx) which is an add-in for Eclipse that can connect to Visual Studio Team System (formerly known as Visual Studio Online) or Team Foundation Server. From there you can check-in code and use many other features of VSTS.